# using beautifulsoup to parse data from table

Tags: python

I tried to use BeautifulSoup to import the data from the table on the link where the rate of gold and silver is given in the table.and I get the following output.. Please tell me how can I get only first information in my output i.e. Rs. 50550 /-. Sorry for asking newbie question. I tried a lot but nothing seems to help.. Thanks in advance.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> response = urlopen('http://goldratenepal.com')
>>> table = soup.findChildren('table')
>>> my_table = table[2]
>>> rows = my_table.findChildren(['th class','tr'])
>>> for row in rows:
    cells = row.findChildren('td')
    for cell in cells:
        value = cell.string
        print value
```

Output:

Rs. 50550 /- 
Rs. 50650 /- 
Rs. 880 /-
Rs.43324/- 
Rs. 43424 /- 
Rs.754 /-

For the information : html file for this webpage looks like this:

```
<table align="center" id="rockartists">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="null">Gold rate of 2013-05-22</th>
            <th class="stones">Gold Rate in Kathmandu</th>
            <th class="stones">Gold Rate in Pokhara</th>
            <th class="u2">Silver</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="">Per 25gm</th>
            <td class="stones">Rs. 50550 /- </td>
            <td class="stones">Rs. 50650 /- </td>
            <td class="u2">Rs. 880 /-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="">Per 10 gm </th>
            <td class="stones">Rs.43324/- </td>
            <td class="stones">Rs. 43424 /- </td>
            <td class="u2">Rs.754 /- </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant html?

Comment: I have added the html file on the post.. Thanks..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply select the first found element that has the `td` tag and the `class="stones"` attribute.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

response = urlopen('http://goldratenepal.com')
html = response.read()
soap = BeautifulSoup(html)
result = soap.find_all('td' ,{'class': 'stones'})

print result[0].text
```